# Login to Secure Website with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Does anyone know how to access a secure website using Mathematica?  I am trying to login using Mathematica's built-in browser and access certain webpages which require a user to be logged in to access them.

Comment: You might find some useful info [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1775/134).

Answer (score 1):

[Upgrade to Mathematica 9](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/full-range-of-web-access-support/), released today, with support for a `"Password"` option in the new [`URLFetch` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/URLFetch.html).